# Height com com min e max em porcentagem x auto

Tags: css, html5, div

Tenho uma `div`, e seu `Height`está com 90%, mas se diminuir a altura do browser o conteúdo sai pra fora da `div`, como posso evitar que saia da `div`?
Pensei em utilizar `height-min:auto` e `height-max:90%` mas não rola. porém se eu deixar com `height:auto`, mas para meu conteúdo não seria o ideal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A parte de cima em azul, seria a `div` com o tamanho de 90% a parte branca é apenas uma margem entre as `div`, a parte preta é outra `div`. A frase até as palavras selecionadas (em azul na parte preta) pertence a `div`azul.

`Códigos`

`divAzul`

```
.div4 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #088fad 20%, #00d5ff 100%);
    margin-top: 4em;
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

`DivPreta`

```
.div5 {
    margin-top: 4em;
    padding: 5em 3em 3em 3em;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

Estou adicionando estas imagens para melhor entender:

com altura menor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

com altura maior:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas o que você quer que ocorra com conteúdo? Seja oculto? A fonte diminua? O texto mantenha a DIV com o tamanho mínimo para ser exibido completamente?

Comment: da uma olhada aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp. Talvez encontre a solução desejada. Aqui é possível testar: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow

Comment: @mauhumor, só quero que a div fique do tamanho mínimo do texto, e o máximo do tamanho 90% da tela, vou olhar os links, obg

Comment: Adicionei algumas imagens a mais para melhor entender